# Force an Azure Pipeline task VSTest@2 to run with an x86 process for an AnyCPU project

Tags: c#, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

In visual studio there's a setting in the Test Explorer called `Processor Architecture for AnyCPU Projects`.  If I set that to `x86` all my tests pass but if I set it to `x64` a few of them fail.  I'm trying to setup an Azure Pipeline (YAML) but I can't seem to figure out how to do the same thing there or if it's even possible.  I've tried setting `platform: 'x86'` but that doesn't seem to do the same thing since the same tests still fail as when it's run in `x64` in visual studio.  (I did also create an `x86` platform in my solution/projects)

For now I've added this line to all the tests that fail in when run in x64:

`if (Environment.Is64BitProcess) Assert.Inconclusive("Fails on x64");`

My YAML for the `VSTest@2` task is pretty much default:

```
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'VSTest (Release)'
  inputs:
    platform: 'x86' #Isn't working
    configuration: 'Release'
```

Comment: Shouldn't you fix the tests in the first place?

Comment: All I needed to do was add a Build task that specifically targeted x86.